# @dnd-kit/sortable : Prevent link from activating when dragged item is dropped

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, dnd-kit

My sortable item contains a link so when I click on it to drag and drop. Problem is after I drop, it navigates to the link. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get isDragging from

```js
const { isDragging } = useDraggable({ id });
```

or

```js
const { isDragging } = useSortable({ id });
```

and then

```javascriptreact
<a href={!isDragging ? 'link' : undefined}>...</a>
```